# storage/app/public/post contents is not in sync to asset public folder

Tags: laravel

I tried to link `storage/app/public/post` to `public folder` using `php artisan storage:link`  but it shows the shortcut file on asset public folder it is not in sync with contents. I am using Laravel 5.5, please help me with this error

Comment: Solved...! after Removing the Storage folder from asset public folder and then again run the , php artisan cache:clear
  "php artisan storage:link"   again worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the storage folder from assets then run `php artisan cache:clear` and rerun the command `php artisan storage:link` you should get it.